# Can Mysql column indexes be kept separately?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am running Mariadb 5.5 and I have a table under the InnoDB schema. Because the size of the table is already very large (700 M rows) and is expected to become even larger, I have indexed some of the columns, for faster searches.

At the same time, we bought an SSD hard disk, where I thought I should put the tmp folder of mysql, so that it can be used for e.g. indexing and become faster. My question is, is it possible to also move the indexes to the SSD folder? Can they be somehow "detached" and put there to make things even faster, or not?

Thanks!

Comment: no. innodb indexes are stored with the table; we assume you've implemented `file_per_table` already. whats most important in terms of indexing is that appropriate indexes have been defined, suitable for the "searches" that are being performed. creating indexes on "some of the columns" sometimes misses the creation of the indexes that will be the most beneficial. sufficiently sized innodb buffer pool will reduce i/o on frequently accessed pages.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There are several typical things that can help shrink the disk footprint and/or speed up queries.

Comment: Thank you for your help! No, I think the file_per_table is not enabled as it seems. Can I do that now? Regarding the SHOW CREATE TABLE, I get:

Comment: Regardless of whether you enable file_per_table, you still can't separate data from indexes. InnoDB stores both types of pages together in the same tablespace for a given table.

Comment: Can I enable `file_per_table` now or must it be done during the creation of the table?

Answer (score 0):

**Table patient_records:**

`CREATE TABLE`patient_records`(`
MRD_sample_FORMAT_id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
DataType`char(1) NOT NULL,`
SequencingOrigin`char(1) NOT NULL,`
ChrNo`varchar(2) NOT NULL,`
ChrPos`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,`
snpID`varchar(20) NOT NULL,`
NuclREF`varchar(500) NOT NULL,`
NuclALT`varchar(3000) NOT NULL,`
QualityLevel`float NOT NULL,`
FilterString`char(1) NOT NULL,`
InfoString`varchar(1000) NOT NULL,`
GT`varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`
AD`varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`
DP`varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`
GQ`varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`
PL`varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY`fk_patients_idx`(`MRD_sample_FORMAT_id`),
  KEY`ChrNo`(`ChrNo`) USING BTREE,
  KEY`snpID`(`snpID`),
  KEY`idx_patient_records_ChrNo`(`ChrNo`),
  KEY`position_chrom`(`ChrPos`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |`

**Table patient_lookup:**

`CREATE TABLE`patient_lookup`(`
MRD_sample_FORMAT_id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
AnalyticalInfo`varchar(150) NOT NULL,`
MRD_SAMPLE_ID`varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MRD_sample_FORMAT_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY`MRD_SAMPLE_ID`(`MRD_SAMPLE_ID`),
  KEY`MRD_SAMPLE_ID_2`(`MRD_SAMPLE_ID`),
  KEY`AnalyticalInfo`(`AnalyticalInfo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |`